# Laravel passing orders to Chart.js

Tags: php, laravel, chart.js

I'm really confused on how to attack this issue. I've got some grouped results (based on sold items) and they are all inside of an array.

```
    $result = Order::where('user_id',Auth::id())->get(['id', 'created_at','price'])->groupBy(function($date) {
        return Carbon::parse($date->created_at)->format('m');
    });
```

The results looks ok I guess:

[image: Results from the code above.]

How would i pass this information to chartjs to get each month and the total "price" for each month to show correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you correctly sorted your data from your server and got a JSON response from, probably you can do something like this in your javascript (btw it is written in es6):

`let myBalanceChart = document.getElementById("monthlyBalanceChart" + stock.id).getContext('2d');
let monthlyBalanceChart = new Chart(myBalanceChart, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: monthlyBalancesMonths,
        datasets: [{
            label: "Monthly Balance",
            data: monthlyBalances,
            backgroundColor: [ // this is for design only
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
            ],
            borderColor: [ // design
            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }],
    },
    options: { // additional options for design/ tooltips
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Monthly Balances This Year',
            fontSize: 25,
        },
        legend: {
            position: 'right',
            fontColor: '#000',
        }
    }
});`

Where `labels` in `data` is a Javascript Array like:
`["January", "February", "March"...]` and so on.

The `data` from `datasets` from `data` is the array based on your monthly prices like:

`[300, 1200, 900, ...]` 
and so on.

And make sure that the array length (or count) of `labels` array must be the same in `data` and properly ordered.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($result as $res){
  $month = $res->created_at->month();//will return month of the timestamp
  $price = $res->price;
}
```

This is how you can retrieve month and price separately and pass it to chart.js in their specified format.

Note: try to understand the json format required by chart.js. Prepare your raw data in that json format and pass it to chart.js
For ex:

```
foreach($result as $res){
  $data[$res->id]['month'] = $res->created_at->month;
  $data[$res->id]['price'] = $res->price;
}
$data=json_encode($data);//this will encode the data array into json format.
```

Now you can pass this to chart.js and get your chart up. (I had done like this once. So this should work)
Also go through the [chart.js google api](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/) for php to understand it better.

Comment: Where are you getting $res->id from? I'm confused.

Comment: Its in your database collection just above created_at in your result